# How to get users with most products

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables:

invoice:

```
invoice_id | user_name | user_id | cost | shop_Id
```

invoice products:

```
id | invoice_id | user_id | product_id | quantity
```

product:

```
product_id | product_name | description
```

I need top 5 customers where shop_id = 1 result & customer have multiple products:

```
invoice_id | user_name | user_id | product_name | product_description
```

Comment: can you please provide data and required output, also explain in detail that in what basis you define the customer as top

Answer (score 0):

You can follow these steps - join the tables, count the products, order by the count and use `LIMIT` :

```
SELECT i.user_name,count(p.product_id) as cnt_products 
FROM invoice i
JOIN invoice_products ip
 ON(i.invoice_id = ip.invoice_id)
JOIN product p
 ON(p.product_id = ip.product_id)
WHERE i.shop_id = 1
GROUP BY i.user_name 
ORDER BY cnt_products DESC
LIMIT 5
```

Comment: Hm, I'm not convinced. Why the products table?

Comment: After a second look, yea, if my solution is what he needs, then product table is indeed not required, but I might misunderstood the question . Lets wait for the OP to comment. @Strawberry